# Stream API map() and filter()

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to learn the Stream API and i came across the below code:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {    
        List <Integer> a = Arrays.asList(2,3,4);
        System.out.println(a.stream().filter(i -> i < 10).average());
    }
}
```

It gives a

> symbol "average()"not found error.

But when I change the sysout with the below it runs fine as expected

```
System.out.println(a.stream().filter(i -> i < 10).mapToInt(i -> i).average());
```

Can someone please explain the difference here?

Comment: You could replace the list with `IntStream.rangeClosed(2, 4)` in order to remove the `mapToInt`

Comment: @cricket_007 when I use Arrays.stream(Arrays.asList()).. and keep the code as it is without the map() method, i am getting the answer as expected..so in this case does the filter method work differently?

Comment: Arrays.stream() accepts an array, not a list object... But assuming you meant to type an array there. As stated in the answer, you get an IntStream. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A- ... The filter has nothing to do with whether or not you can calculate the average

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `Stream<T>` has no `average()` method, since the element type `T` can be any reference type, which doesn't necessarily have a meaning for calculation of the average of the `Stream` elements.

On the other hand, an `IntStream` has an `average()` method, since it has `int` elements, for which the average operation is well defined.

Therefore you must convert a `Stream<Integer>` to an `IntStream` (via `mapToInt()`) in order to call `average()`.

Comment: when I use Arrays.stream(Arrays.asList()).. and keep the code as it is without the map, i am getting the answer as expected..so in this case does the filter method work differently?

Comment: @ghostrider `Arrays.stream()` expects an array, not a List, so `Arrays.stream(Arrays.asList())` wouldn't pass compilation.

Comment: Apologies for the typo, i tried with Arrays.stream(new int[] {2,3,4}) without the map() and worked fine

Comment: @ghostrider `Arrays.stream(new int[] {2,3,4})` returns an `IntStream`, which has an `average` method. On the other hand, `Arrays.stream(new Integer[] {2,3,4})` would return a `Stream<Integer>` which doesn't have `average` method.

Comment: @ghostrider Instead of `Arrays.stream(new int[] {2,3,4})` you can use `IntStream.of(2, 3, 4)`. By the way, `.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).filter(i -> i < 10)` is slightly more efficient than `.stream().filter(i -> i < 10).mapToInt(i -> i)` as it avoids an unboxing operation at `i < 10`.

Answer (score 3):

To explain it a bit more in detail:

This is giving you a `List` of `Integer` (the arguments are boxed from `int` to `Integer`):

```
List <Integer> a = Arrays.asList(2,3,4);
```

The following statement is converting your `List<Integer>` into a `Stream<Integer>`

```
a.stream()
```

Now filtering still preserves the type `Stream<Integer>`, and `Stream` doesn't provide a method called `average()` (as it can consist of any generic type).

Calling `mapToInt(i -> i)` converts your `Stream<Integer>` into an `IntStream`, which does have a method called `average()`. Note that `i -> i` is a `ToIntFunction<Integer>`, which converts an `Integer` back to an `int` due to auto-unboxing.

Another way to fix that would be

```
System.out.println(IntStream.of(2,3,4).filter(i -> i < 10).average());
```

Answer (score 2):

Expressing calculations as chains is convenient, but sometimes it hides type information that might be useful to understanding what's going on.  Try rewriting

```
List <Integer> a = Arrays.asList(2,3,4);
System.out.println(a.stream().filter(i -> i < 10).average());
```

where every result has an explicit type (your IDE should help you.)  Then you get:

```
List <Integer> a = Arrays.asList(2,3,4);
Stream<Integer> s1 = a.stream();
Stream<Integer> s2 = s1.filter((Integer i) -> i < 10);
double average = s2.average();
```

When you write it this way, you'll see that you're trying to invoke a nonexistent method on `Stream<Integer>`.  You want an `IntStream`, which does have an `average()` method.  So you can rewrite as:

```
List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(2,3,4);
Stream<Integer> s1 = a.stream();
IntStream s2 = s1.mapToInt((Integer i) -> i);
IntStream s3 = s2.filter((Integer i) -> i < 10);
double average = s3.average();
```

and everything is good.  Then you can roll it back up with chaining and implicit lambdas:

```
double average = a.stream()
                  .mapToInt(i -> i)
                  .filter(i -> i<10)
                  .average();
```

The lesson here is: when you're confused, unroll complex expressions into simpler ones with manifest types.  Often, this helps you spot the problem immediately; if not, it generally results in a more informative compiler error.

(If you use IntelliJ, you can use the "extract variable" refactor to pull a subexpression into a local variable with its inferred type.)

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList(2,3,4).stream()` would given you `Stream<Integer>` which is of type Stream and it does not have any average() method, hence the error.

`Arrays.asList(2,3,4).mapToInt()` would return IntStream which is one of the four primitive specialized classes provided by Stream API and it has average() method, hence it works.